# Installation of Tensorflow gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am trying to install Tensorflow GPU but this error keeps popping up on my Anaconda prompt. What should I do?

```
Could not install packages due to an  EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] 
Access is denied: 'c:\\users\\hp user\\anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\.libs\\libopenblas.BNVRK7633HSX7YVO2TADGR4A5KEKXJAW.gfortran-win_amd64.dll' 
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Comment: Have you tried running `cmd` as administrator?

Comment: Did you also try what the last line of the message says?

Comment: are you installing tensorflow-gpu using pip

Answer (score 0):

The user account you are using does not have access to perform a global installation via pip, you need to add the --user command in your command e.g

`pip install tensorflow-gpu --user`

Answer (score 0):

The problem because of permission issue therefore you have to open `cmd` as administrator mode and run below command

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```